How to sort in descending order using powershell based on lastwritetime if the format is D/m/yyyy
I need to sort through multiple files in my blob. However the modified date is in d/m/yyyy format. Hence the sorting is incorrect.
This is what I am currently using in my script.
Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") -Descending

You need to pass some input (the sequence of values to be sorted) to Sort-Object:
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt
$sortedTxtFiles = $txtFiles |Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending


I tried this but as I mentioned earlier that the modified date in my blob is in DD/MM/YYYY and so still sorting is not correct

Lowercase m indicate MINUTES when formatting dates, not Months(have some docs). This would easily mess your sorting.
Also: if LastWriteTime is a File property then it's a DateTime object.
It should be sorted correctly with just Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending
Details on the content and type of the object you are passing are necessary to further analysis

I have to sort through multiple .txt files based on the modified date which is in DD/MM/YYYY format. I tried on what you suggested but it's not sorting as per sequence

please update your post explaining how you get your data and, possibly, an example of them.

Basically it's a very simple flow. We are receiving.txt files everyday in a 'Landing' folder which is created in my storage account. Every Friday I need to copy that day's file and place in another folder. However the script is failing to copy that day's file instead a random file is being copied. I have already added in my script to copy the top 1 file after sorting. Not sure what else is to be modified. Also the same script is working fine in another module. The only difference I see is in the format of modified date in the blob. sorting is correct when  the modified date is in MM/DD/YYYY

please, update your post with the relevant pieces of code: especially the cmdlet you are using to pipe data to Sort-Object. Example: Get-ChildItem $Path | where-object { $_ -is $stuff_i_want } | Sort-object -Property whatever | Move-Item $_.fullname -Destination $whereIwantIt
